# Displaying Image file from Database React JS and Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, formidable

I am having an issue displaying an image file from my mongodb database to my Profile and EditProfile component. when I upload the file with my Editprofile component it saves to the database, but when I want to retrieve it to view the image file in my profile component I got a broken image in return and if I use an `alt` the `alt` is what is return in the view. 
I used formidable on `PUT` method to save the image file to my database and I set it as a buffer data on my database user model, something like this

```
photo: {
     data: buffer,
     contentType: string
}
```

this  is what is being returned after the data is saved on the database successfully

```
{ photo:
   { contentType: 'image/jpeg',
     data:
      Binary {
        _bsontype: 'Binary',
        sub_type: 0,
        position: 780831,
        buffer:
         <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 02 01 00 60 00 60 00 00 ff ee 00 0e 41 64 6f 62 65 00 64 00 00 00 00 01 ff e1 14 23 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a ... > } },
  _id: 5ea23ae949389a14c8dab6c8,
  name: 'name',
  email: 'name@gmail.com',
  salt: '0.9588954503373059',
  hashed_password: '3f9867a4786e8944d565653959110698cdcc196c',
  created: 2020-04-24T01:03:37.457Z,
  __v: 0,
  about: 'Getting to my greatness',
  updated: 2020-05-05T00:47:53.899Z }
```

Now the issue is displaying the image on profile view component, i am using an `api` endpoint to display the photo which i created a route and controller for
route.js

```
router.route('/api/users/photo/:userId')
    .get(userControl.photo, userControl.defaultPhoto)
router.route('/api/users/defaultphoto')
    .get(userControl.defaultPhoto)
```

controller.js

```
const photo = (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.profile.photo.data) {
        res.set("Content-Type", res.profile.photo.contentType)
        return res.send(req.profile.photo.data)
    }
    next()
}

const defaultPhoto = (req, res) => {
    return res.sendFile(profilePic)
}
```

Then in my Profile view component i called the `api` like this in the render method of the class component

```
render() {
        const {classes} = this.props
        const {redirectToSignin, user} = this.state
        const photoUrl = user._id
            ? `/api/users/photo/${user._id}?${new Date().getTime()}`
            : `/api/users/defaultphoto`
        if(redirectToSignin) {
            return (<Redirect to="/signin"/>)
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <Paper className={classes.root} elevation={4}>
                    <Typography type="title" className={classes.title}>Profile</Typography>
                    <List dense>
                        <ListItem>
                            <ListItemAvatar>
                                <Avatar src={photoUrl} className={classes.bigAvatar}/>
                            </ListItemAvatar>

                            <ListItemText primary={user.name} secondary={user.email}/>
                            {auth.isAuthenticated().user && auth.isAuthenticated().user._id == user._id &&
                              (<ListItemSecondaryAction>
                                    <Link to={'/user/edit/' + user._id}>
                                        <IconButton aria-label="Edit" color="primary">
                                            <Edit/>
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </Link>
                                    <DeleteUser userId={user._id}/>
                              </ListItemSecondaryAction>)}
                        </ListItem>
                        <Divider/>
                        <ListItem>
                            <ListItemText primary={user.about} secondary={"Joined: " + (new Date(user.created).toDateString())}/>
                        </ListItem>
                    </List>
                </Paper>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I am using a material ui `Avatar` to display the image and nothing displaying i have also tried html `img` element still doesnt work

```
const photoUrl = user._id
      ? `/api/users/photo/${user._id}?${new Date().getTime()}`
      : `/api/users/defaultphoto`

<ListItemAvatar>
    <Avatar src={photoUrl} className={classes.bigAvatar}/>
</ListItemAvatar>
```

i need help in solving this issue will really appreciate one. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend to avoid storing the image itself in the database, there is an easier way to do this.

Let's say that you upload the image via `type='file'` input.
In your react handling form event, you can take the file name, example :

```
// Handling file input change event
const onChangeFile = e => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
}

// Handling form submit
const onSubmitForm = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (File) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', File);
        try {
            const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/yourRoute', formData);

        }
        catch (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Please enter all fields");
    }
}`
```

Now in the back end, you store only the image `path + name` as imgUrl field :

```
router.route('/add').post( function (req, res) {
var file = req.files.file
file.mv("your-react-image-folder-path" + file.name, err => {
if (err) {
 console.error(err);
 return res.status(500).send(err);
}
});
            var yourNewModel = new Model({
                imgUrl: "/your-react-image-folder-path/" + file.name,
            yourNewModel.save()
                .then(data => {
                    res.status(200).json(data);
                })
                .catch(err => res.status(400).json({ msg: err }));
        }
    })

  });
```

Finally the display in react app will be easy, if you fetch your data it would be something like this :

```
{YourVariable.map(element =>
    <Img variant="top" src={element.imgUrl} />

 )}
```

Note : this code was written using react hooks and functional components.

Comment: am not trying to display the image from a particular path am trying to upload a profile pic for a authorized user so the user can actually pick the image from any path location

Comment: I just need a way to convert the buffer object in the database so the image can display

Comment: @el-Mehdi loukach I am stuck with this question, could you please help if you earlier work on similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62323808/save-image-path-in-database-and-display-the-image-in-front-end